# Programming Discord Bot to link twitch account

Tags: javascript

Im trying to figure out how to make it so that when a user in my discord server types "!link " they can link their account and have their name changed to their account name automatically

This is for a discord streaming community im starting up, this runs Javascript, I am in a bit of a road block trying to figure this out

```
$.getJSON('https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/' + YOUR_CHANNEL_NAME, function(channel) {

  if (channel["stream"] == null) {

  } else {



  }



});
```

I still need the command which i haven't quite figured out yet either

I want users in my discord to link their twitch accounts using a command like this "!link "

Comment: yeah its what i got, im just having a lot of trouble lol

Comment: I can asure you i have been trying to figure this out all night, im new to programming and just wanted to get some help